# awk call with single quotation marks for AWS cli

Tags: awk

I'm trying to get all key values from a DynamoDB table and call delete-item like:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name SomeCount --filter-expression "requestCount > :threshold" --expression-attribute-values '{":threshold":{"N":"2"}}' --max-items 2 | jq '.Items[].SomeKey.S' | awk  '{ print aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name SomeCount --key "{\"SomeKey\": {\"S\": $1 }}" }'
```

Before the `awk` command, it prints:

```
somekey1
somekey2
...
```

Also, `aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name SomeCount --key '{"SomeKey": {"S": $1 }}'` works well.

But combined one shows:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name SomeCount --filter-expression "requestCount > :threshold" --expression-attribute-values '{":threshold":{"N":"2"}}' --max-items 2 | jq '.Items[].SomeKey.S' \
    | awk  '{ print aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name SomeCount --key "{\"SomeKey\": {\"S\": $1 }}" }'
    awk: { aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name SomeCount --key "{\"SomeKey\": {\"S\": $1 }}" }
awk:                      ^ syntax error
```

How can I fix this issue?

=== UPDATE ===
In the original question, I added `print` like `awk: { print aws dynamodb ... }` by mistake. The comments below from commenters are addressing my mistakes. But for better understanding of future readers, I've updated the question above.

Comment: for `print aws dyna...`, each term, `aws, `dynamodb`, `delete-item`, .... is being considered as a variable. You probably want` awk '{print "awk dyamodb ..."}`. You'll have to figure out what you need to use from the std awk line array of `$0`, or `$1,$2,$3....$NF`. Good luck.

Comment: When you wrote `awk '{ print aws dynamodb delete-item ...` were you trying to get awk to print a string `aws dynamodb delete-item...` or to execute a command `aws dynamodb delete-item ...`?

Comment: Sorry, that `print` was added for my testing. I want to execute the command. I will update the question.

Comment: Don't add a note under an "UPDATE" heading, actually **update** the example (which as of now still has a `print` in it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to get awk to print the string (assuming some value for the $1 placeholder):

```
aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name SomeCount --key '{"SomeKey": {"S": $1 }}'
```

this is what you want:

```
awk  '{ print "aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name SomeCount --key \047{\"SomeKey\": {\"S\": " $1 " }}\047" }'
```

If you're trying to get awk to execute that command - don't as awk is a tool for manipulating text while the tool to sequence calls to tools is a shell. This might be what you want (replace your `| awk ...` with this `| xargs ...`):

```
xargs -n 1 -I {} aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name SomeCount --key '{"SomeKey": {"S": {} }}'
```